# Pop-up box not opening

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a pop-up box open upon clicking on a link...I found this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/rxGmk/  and applied it, however I'm failing to get the popup to open. The below code is part of a frameset. I used the same CSS. PS: the jsfiddle is working.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">


<script>
var opener = document.getElementById("opener");

opener.onclick = function(){

    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox"),
        dimmer = document.createElement("div");

    dimmer.style.width =  window.innerWidth + 'px';
    dimmer.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    dimmer.className = 'dimmer';

    dimmer.onclick = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this);   
        lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    document.body.appendChild(dimmer);

    lightbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
    lightbox.style.top = window.innerHeight/2 - 50 + 'px';
    lightbox.style.left = window.innerWidth/2 - 100 + 'px';
    return false;
}
</script>
</HEAD>

<body>

     <div id="lightbox">Testing out the lightbox</div>
<a href="#" id="opener">Click me</a>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: the fiddle works?  Not sure what the question is

Comment: Check your console. Lately I've experienced my JS not running due to chrome extensions. Let us know what your console says.

Comment: Can you also include the CSS, so we know how your hiding lightbox initially.

Comment: Just a quick note: since you are using the HTML5 doctype, you really don't need to use capitalized tags.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz nothing in the console

Comment: Fiddle works for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be friends with 'Inspect Element' like developer tools.
In the console, it used to say your error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

It's because you are calling `document.getElementById("opener");` in your  while your opener element is in the body.

Your script will be loaded when the document is loaded BEFORE body tag.

Make sure you have your script after where your `opener` is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- you can replace with your link to css file -->
    <style>
        #lightbox{
          visibility:hidden;
          position:absolute;
          background:red;
          border:2px solid #3c3c3c;
          color:white;
          z-index:100;
          width: 200px;
          height:100px;
          padding:20px;
        }

        .dimmer{
          background: #000;
          position: absolute;
          opacity: .5;
          top: 0;
          z-index:99;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="lightbox">Testing out the lightbox</div>
  <a href="#" id="opener">Click me</a>

  <!-- script is added after id="opener" is defined -->
  <script>
    var opener = document.getElementById("opener");

    opener.onclick = function(){

    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox"),
        dimmer = document.createElement("div");

    dimmer.style.width =  window.innerWidth + 'px';
    dimmer.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    dimmer.className = 'dimmer';

    dimmer.onclick = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this);   
        lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    document.body.appendChild(dimmer);

    lightbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
    lightbox.style.top = window.innerHeight/2 - 50 + 'px';
    lightbox.style.left = window.innerWidth/2 - 100 + 'px';
    return false;
  }
</script>

</body>


</html>
```

In general, I define any javascript at the end of the `<body>` tag because it is one of the optimization strategies to improve initial loading speed of the website.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to web development! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing something in your code that the jsFiddle does. By default, it wraps the code in the JavaScript window into a window.onload event handler. Because your code does not do this, your JavaScript runs before your opener link is created, so the click handler doesn't get applied. To fix this, put your JavaScript in a window.onload handler like the jsFiddle does for you:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var opener = document.getElementById("opener");

  opener.onclick = function(){

    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox"),
        dimmer = document.createElement("div");

    dimmer.style.width =  window.innerWidth + 'px';
    dimmer.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    dimmer.className = 'dimmer';

    dimmer.onclick = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this);   
        lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    document.body.appendChild(dimmer);

    lightbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
    lightbox.style.top = window.innerHeight/2 - 50 + 'px';
    lightbox.style.left = window.innerWidth/2 - 100 + 'px';
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: still nothing...Could it be because the html is part of a frameset?